# Display three dot (...) after description?

Tags: php

I usage this php code to display recent post with description. Max desc 100 word. How to display 3 dot after 100 word (like this: **this is content of bla bla bla...** ).

Can someone help me, please!

This is my php code:

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://domain.com/feed/');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
$item = array (
'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
);
array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
$title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
$link = $feed[$x]['link'];
$description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
$description = substr($description, 0, 138); 
$date = date('d F Y - H:m', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
echo '<li><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong>';
echo '<br><small>'.$date.'</small>';
echo '<br>'.$description.'</br></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: exactly after 100th word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look in your code like this, but this is counting each sign, not words:

```
if(strlen($description) > 138) {
    $description = substr($description, 0, 138).'&hellip;'; 
}
```

In case you want to use words, do something like this:

```
// put this function above your code....
function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit=100, $ending = '&hellip;') { 
    $words = explode(' ', $string); 
    if(count($words) > $word_limit) {
        return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $word_limit)).$ending; 
    }
    return $string;
}

// and use it like this...
echo '<br>'.string_limit_words($description).'</br></li>';
```

Comment: Thank you Michel for help me. How to show 3 dot (...) after description?? please help?

Comment: `echo '<br>'.string_limit_words($description).'...</br></li>';` or alternatively instead of `...` you can use `&hellip;`

Comment: OMG, i dont know about "&hellip;". Thank you, i will try now.

Comment: @axel.michel Oh I'm sorry, I totally missed that!